# What does the number 16 in the DLL symbol _FooBar@16 represent?

Tags: dll, symbols

What does the number 16 in the DLL symbol `_FooBar@16` represent?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you care about the decorated name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that _FooBar is a __stdcall function that takes 16 bytes of parameters.

32-bit calling conventions on x86 are described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/08/48616.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This is general name mangling and depends upon the calling convention of the function.

The various calling conventions and name mangling applied to functions is documented as [Argument Passing and Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx). You will have to click the individual links to see the exact mangling applied.

In your case, you have a `__stdcall` convention which uses the following naming convention:

> An underscore (_) is prefixed to the
>   name. The name is followed by the at
>   sign (@) followed by the number of
>   bytes (in decimal) in the argument
>   list. Therefore, the function declared
>   as int func( int a, double b ) is
>   decorated as follows: _func@12